# Can Lightroom/Photoshop work well together when using Smart Filters?

Tags: lightroom, photoshop

I have the latest Lightroom and Photoshop CC. In Lightroom, I select a picture and then click Edit in Photoshop. The picture is a JPG and a new JPG is created, with the same name and the "-Edit" suffix.

I want to add some filters to the picture, so, I enable smart filters. I work on it and when I close it, it asks me to save a PSD file, and I just accept what Photoshop is offering me as the default.

Back in Lightroom, all my changes are nowhere to be seen, the JPG for the edited one looks the same as the original one and on the file system I can see an extra PSD that Lightroom seems to be ignoring.

Is it possible to have a good workflow with Lightroom and Photoshop **and** Smart Filters?

Comment: In properties how to you set to export to PS? Because for me it work fine and new PSD is automatically added in LR

Comment: @RomeoNinov I'm not sure I understand your first question.

Comment: When you edit in Photoshop it use config you define in LR properties. How did you set there to be (PSD, TIFF, 8 bit, 16 bit, etc.)

Comment: @RomeoNinov do you mean, what I saved it as?

Comment: I  mean this: https://imgur.com/Pq4D7qE

Comment: @RomeoNinov ahhh... I didn't know about that. Setting both as PSD and using Edit as Smart Object made it work. Thank you sa much... back to editing now. Do you want to write it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: You are welcome, Pupeno. Answer added :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set in Edit->Preferences->External Editing both to be PSD as it is on the image below.
[image]
and then try to edit as Smart Object. You may need to restart LR in this case.